# How do you update based on a multiple field join

Tags: sql, hive

I’m trying to run a update based on a multiple field join.

Hive sql updates seem very limited.
They seem to only allow a update join based on in(which I don’t think works with multiple keys)

Answer (score 0):

your answer:

```
UPDATE A
SET aField1=B.Field AND aField2=C.Field
FROM table1 A
INNER JOIN table2 B ON B.KEY1=A.KEY1
INNER JOIN table3 C ON C.KEY2=A.KEY2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this :

```
UPDATE TABLE2
       JOIN TABLE1
       ON TABLE2.SERIAL_ID = TABLE1.SUBST_ID
SET    TABLE2.BRANCH_ID = TABLE1.CREATED_ID;
```